# Составить правило для htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Есть URL вида:

```
site.com/page.php?p=admin
site.com/page.php?p=contacts
```

Хотелось бы получить

```
site.com/admin
site.com/contacts
```

Comment: что пробовали ?

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ul.hol.es$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ul.hol.es$

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?p=$1 [L]


не работает

Comment: Товарищи........ всё глухо(

Comment: наверное надо хотя-бы

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)[/]{0,1}$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Отлично работает!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/$ page.php?p=admin [L]
RewriteRule ^contacts/$ page.php?p=contacts [L]
```